# is it possible to start a conversation from a servlet or a filter

Tags: java, servlets, jboss7.x, java-ee-6, java-ee-7

I am using java ee 6 and trying to find out if it is possible to start a conversation from a servlet or a filter. so far I have the following code:

a method:

```
private static HttpConversationContext getHttpConversationContext() {
    return Container.instance().deploymentManager().instance().select(HttpConversationContext.class).get();
}
```

and then i have :

```
final HttpConversationContext httpConversationContext = getHttpConversationContext();
httpConversationContext.associate((HttpServletRequest) request);
httpConversationContext.getCurrentConversation().begin(conversationId);
```

But this does not seem to work. Also when i try to check if the conversation began with the following code:

```
Conversation conversation = httpConversationContext.getConversation(conversationId);
```

the conversation is always null, since the previous code did not work.

Any clue how to do it in the right way?

Please note although jboss7 is used in the tag, i dont mind if the solution related to another server is posted, ie. wildfly.

Many Thanks.

Comment: `HttpConversationContext`, and I guess `Container` and `Conversation`, are JBoss-specific classes, they are not part of any released version of the Servlet API.  Please retag your question (remove [java-ee-*] and add the appropriate JBoss tags).  I'd do it for you, but I don't know your JBoss details.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger for your comment, I am using jboss 7, please feel free to change the tags. but i am also wondering if it is possible to achieve such kind of thing with server agnostic codes. also the associated technologies are still java ee 6/7, so it might give the readers some clue. maybe such things could be achieved in a different way. not necessarily the way i am doing.

Comment: Why dont you just inject conversation into the filter or servlet, hoping you are using servlet 3+ api cause they support injection

Comment: you cant @maress as conversation scope is not present in servlet context

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in a Java EE fashion, then you should inject a [Conversation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/ConversationScoped.html) Scoped Session bean into the Servlet.

Comment: Conversation scope is not present in the servlet context.